# How to update updated time field in MongoDB only if document other fields got changed in single query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

How to do this in a single mongo query (we should not update the updated field always, only update if other fields got modified)

```
write_results_obj = db[collection].update_one(query, {update_key: record}, upsert=upsert)
if write_results_obj.modified_count > 0:
    db[collection].update_one(query, {updated: datetime.utcnow()})
```

Comment: just put both fields in update part `{ update_key: record, updated: datetime.utcnow() }`

Comment: @turivishal I thougth that too at first, but with that aproach, you will ALWAYS update the document because the date is different. However if possible that there was no other changes.

Comment: @turivishal It will update updated field always irrespective of other fields modified or not

Comment: @venkatesh, did you find a solution to this?